# Can I check if my API key is sufficiently hidden in node.js to push to github?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a small web app I'm creating by following a node.js tutorial and would like to push to github. I'm using the requests package along with dotenv to hide my API key in a .env file and I've put .env into my gitignore. This is the code for the app.js file:

```html
const request = require('request');
require('dotenv').config();

const api_key = process.env.API_KEY;

const url = `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/${api_key}/37.8267,-122.4233`;

request({ url: url }, (error, response) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(response.body);
    console.log(data.currently);
});
```

#### Question

Have I sufficiently hidden my API key? If I pushed this and someone were to clone my repo, would the API key be exposed at all in the process object or anywhere else? Is there a way to check this before a commit/push?

Comment: Yes, not committing the `.env` file that contains the key is sufficient. I think there also are tools (used as pre-commit hooks or github web hooks) that complain when you push something that looks too much like an API key, but asking for those is off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: I would still include an `example.env` file with default/placeholder values and maybe a readme to remind your future self that you need the `.env` file to run the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the key is only in your `.env` and your `.env` isn't in github, you're fine. This is very standard practice.

You can verify that you're not about to push it up by running `git status` on your command line after `git commit`ting your changes.